Is it possible to build a KMM iOS project in Mac Catalyst?
I am working in a KMM project. Now I am curious about if I can build the project in mac-catalyst using xcode.
I am working in a KMM project. Now I am curious about if I can build the project in mac-catalyst using xcode.
I want to know that if this is possible or not

Not yet as of September 2024, see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-40442/Support-building-Kotlin-Native-for-Mac-Catalyst-x86-64-and-arm64#focus=Comments-27-9835296.0-0
